# Program not running properly

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, boolean

I'm trying to write a program where the user can name the robot and do tasks afterward. My problems are:

1.) after the user enter the name for the robot for the first time, the user has to enter the 'enter'  key for the next String to appear. (I want the next String after user input to appear after entering the name immediately.)

2.) The String after the first user input is ("Are you sure you want to name your robot " + r1.name + "?"); However, the console does not display the r1.name part.

EDIT:

3.) If I enter a something other than 1 or 2. The console displays:

Please enter an appropriate answer.
Are you sure you want to name your robot ?

It does not display the name that I entered earlier. Anyway to fix it?

The following is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class robot {
String name;
double time;

void print() {
    System.out.println("My name is " + name + ".");
}

void command() {
}

}

public class t1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    robot r1 = new robot();

    System.out.println("Please enter a name for your robot: ");
    r1.name = input.nextLine();

    boolean confirm = false;
    while (confirm == false) {
        r1.name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Are you sure you want to name your robot "
                + r1.name + "?");
        System.out.println("1) Yes");
        System.out.println("2) No");
        switch (input.nextInt()) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Your robot has been named as " + r1.name
                    + ".");
            confirm = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Please enter a name for your robot: ");
            r1.name = input.nextLine();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Please enter an appropriate answer.");
            break;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the issue should be fixed by commenting out the first `r1.name = input.nextLine();` -

```
// r1.name = input.nextLine();
boolean confirm = false;
while (confirm == false) {
    r1.name = input.nextLine();
```

You ignore that String anyway and enter the `confirm == false` while loop. That could be

```
while (! confirm) { // <-- using NOT.
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `r1.name = input.nextLine();` twice. The second time(inside your `while` loop) it reads the `nextLine()` which is not the name you entered. Try removing one of the `r1.name = input.nextLine();`